# Spring @RequestMapping value vs. name annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Trying to find the answer but somehow was unable to.
If you define your REST interface in Spring like this:

```
@RequestMapping("hello")
public class HeloREST {
```

What is the difference to a definition with value annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "hello")
public class HeloREST {
```

Answer (score 1):

Both are identical. The `value` element is only really needed where more than one  element is present, e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hello/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Reimeus's answer, In general case the annotation must have a `value()` named attribute in order to write in the shorter way, and of course the `RequestMapping` does.

```
String[] value() default {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Java annotations can declare whatever fields they like.

But, if they declare one simply called `value`, then it gets special treatment.

That field (and that one alone) is allowed to be omitted, like in your example.  And it can only be omitted if it's used on its own.

That's true for all annotations.